# Inquiry on Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, denmark

I really love to visit Denmark by June. But I was refused and I dont have any idea why. Can I inquire to the Danish Immigration Services the reason why I was refused? They have this website www.newtodenmark.dk/contact-us where there is a contact form.

Comment: Do you have the refusal letter?..

Comment: You should have a refusal letter with specific reason(s) provided for the refusal, which you should include in your question.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, I have. I wanna know the main reason because I want to re apply or appeal.

Comment: Which is better to re apply or to appeal?

Comment: Please upload a scan of the refusal letter. You can see a manual on how to do it here: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-do-i-upload-an-image/4090#4090

Comment: The refusal gives you the reason you were refused. Now Schengen refusals are not very detailed unlike UK refusals so without a background of your case there is very little we can glean from it to advise you.

Comment: @JonathanReez I really dont know to upload the file. Is there any other way that I can upload the file?

Answer (score 4):

In the question you asked yesterday, you said that you did did not submit all the required documents, that you failed to include a letter of approved leave. The rejection notice you received should tell you what you can do next, including appealing or reapplying. If you were rejected solely because of a missing document, the application can be re-opened. You can use the link below to email Immigration.

> [Appeal](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/visa/appeal.htm)
>
> Danish embassies and consulates occasionally reject visa applications. These decisions can be appealed to the Danish Immigration Service.
>
> The rejection notice will indicate whether the decision is to be appealed to the Danish Immigration Service, the Immigrations Appeals Board or to the Ministry of Immigration and Integration, how to appeal, and whether there is deadline for appeal.
>
> If the Danish Immigration Service rejects a visa application, the decision can be appealed to the Ministry of Immigration and Integration. The Immigration Service’s rejection notice will provide instructions for appealing.
>
> The vast majority of rejections issued by an embassy or consulate are automatically sent to the Danish Immigration Service for appeal. The applicant does not need to request an appeal.
>
> **Re-opening applications**
>
> An application can be re-opened if it was rejected due to insufficient information.
>
> The applicant or the Danish host can submit a request to re-open an application, together with the additional documentation, to the organisation that issued the initial rejection.
>
> If the new information is sufficient, the application will be re-opened. Please note, however, that an application can only be re-opened if the new documentation relates to the information that was available at the time the decision was made.

Here is the page with an [online form to email the Immigration Service](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/contact/contact_to_the_danish_immigration_service/contact_form/contactform2.htm) regarding your application.